# How do I check Dataflow health whether it is up or down using Stackdriver?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-stackdriver

I want to check the Cloud Dataflow job health whether it is up or down at this time? Is there any option in Stackdriver to display the dataflow health?

Answer (score 0):

I not aware of a way to track this using Stackdriver but you can observe the status of Google Cloud Dataflow Service (and other services offered by Google Cloud) using the dashboard [here](https://status.cloud.google.com/).